# Trigger, Views or something else?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, triggers, database-view

I have some tables to describe a trips. Table `stops` keeps intermediate stops of trips. Table `trip` has an attribute `type` witch indicates on which continent the trip was made.

```
CREATE TABLE continent (
    id_continent SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,    
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE    /* like 'europe', 'asia' etc */
);

CREATE TABLE port (
    id_port SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_continent INT,  
    FOREIGN KEY (id_continent) REFERENCES continent (id_continent)
);

CREATE TABLE trip (
    id_trip SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR(10) CHECK (type IN ('europe', 'asia', 'africa', 'inter'))
);

CREATE TABLE stops (
    id_stop SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_trip INT,
    id_port INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_trip) REFERENCES trip (id_trip),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_port) REFERENCES port (id_port)
);
```

also I've create view `view_stops_continents` as join `continent`, `port` and `stops` which made :

```
id_trip  id_port id_continent
-------+--------+-------------
10     |  16    |   1
10     |  7     |   1
10     |  54    |   1
12     |  91    |   2
12     |  12    |   1
32     |  11    |   3
32     |  24    |   3
```

so I need to UPDATE field `type` in table `trip` according this view
I mean if for `id_trip` all `id_continent` are the same set `type` as name of this continent, else set type 'inter'
for example here for `id_trip` = 10 `type` will be 'europe' and for `id_trip` = 12 it will be 'inter'
and the table trip from

```
SELECT * FROM trip;

id_trip   type   
-------+--------
 10    | 
 12    | 
 32    |
```

should become

```
SELECT * FROM trip;

id_trip   type   
-------+--------
 10    | 'europe'
 12    | 'inter'
 32    | 'asia'
```

how can I do it?

UPD: I try to make it by views, for example I've made this one:

```
   id_trip    type 
-----------+--------------            
        10 | Europe
        32 | Africa
        12 | Asia
        12 | Europe
```

how to use it to set attribute `type` in table `trip` ?

Comment: Can you show the updated output you should get, given the inputs you provided? @pinkiBet

Comment: Have you tried using the `UPDATE` command?

Comment: sure, I've made 

`UPDATE trip SET (id_trip, type) = (SELECT id_trip, trip FROM new_view WHERE new_view.id_trip = trip.id_trip);
`
But there is an error
`
psql:test.sql:96: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
`